# Retrive & Display a PDF document from SharePoint Document Library to a html canvas using Javascript

Tags: javascript, office-365, sharepoint-rest-api, pdf

In SharePoint hosted App I need to get a specific PDF document from SharePoint Document Library & display its 1st page to a HTML canvas using JavaScript.

For that, I tried to retrieve the PDF file using RestAPI & then render the 1st page in canvas using pdf.js

The problem is when I trying to Implement this canvas binding with blank page.

Here is the Code:

```
function execCrossDomainRequest() {
// executor: The RequestExecutor object    
// Initialize the RequestExecutor with the app web URL.    
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);

executor.executeAsync(  
  {  
      url:appweburl +
        "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/SiteName/LibraryName/sample.pdf')/$value?@target='" +
         hostweburl + "'",
      method: "GET",
      binaryStringResponseBody: true,

      headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },                   
      success: function (data) {
          //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

          var blob = new Blob([data.body], { type: "application/pdf" });
          var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

          RenderToCanvas(fileURL);

          },
      error: function (err) {    
              alert("error: " + JSON.stringify(err));    
          }      

      });                                  
}
```

And render function is,

```
function RenderToCanvas(fileURL){
    PDFJS.getDocument({ url: fileURL }).then(function (pdf_doc) {
      __PDF_DOC = pdf_doc;
      debugger;
      // Show the first page
      var page_no = 1;

 __PDF_DOC.getPage(page_no).then(function (page) {

          __CANVAS = $("#pdf-canvas").get(0);
          __CANVAS_CTX = __CANVAS.getContext('2d');
          // As the canvas is of a fixed width we need to set the scale of the viewport accordingly
          var scale_required = __CANVAS.width / page.getViewport(1).width;
          // Get viewport of the page at required scale
          var viewport = page.getViewport(scale_required);

          // Set canvas height
          __CANVAS.height = viewport.height;

          var renderContext = {
              canvasContext: __CANVAS_CTX,
              viewport: viewport
          };

          // Render the page contents in the canvas
          page.render(renderContext).then(function () {
            //code after rendering
          });

      });
  }).catch(function (error) {
      // If error
      alert(error.message);

  });;

}
```

please help...

Comment: what is the error you are getting? Or the Page is not getting displayed? it will be great if you can provide Error details/Screen shot

Comment: there is no error getting in the console. It's just displaying 1st page as blank.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of downloading the file why not just embed the pdf in the page using an html tag:

```
<embed src="<PATH TO SP DO LIBRARY FOLDER>/file_name.pdf" width="800px" height="2100px" />
```

Then, use again javascript to unable page rotation.

Or you could use an iframe as well:

```
<iframe src="<PATH TO SP DO LIBRARY FOLDER>/file_name.pdf" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;border: none;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work, because SharePoint Online does not allow cross-domain iframe requests. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/security/cross-domain-iframe-requests-are-blocked